# For some reason I can not produce accented characters in console [ é, ü, etc. ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

This was working fine until a Mac OS update. I reinstalled RVM, rails, ruby, everything. Nothing works so far.

In my Mac Terminal, I can produce a `é`, but once in console, I can produce the character, with `alt + character`, and then when I type the letter that character is assigned to, it deletes the character.

In my `~/.rvmrc` :

```
export ruby_configure_flags="--with-readline-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4"
```

Any ideas?

I've gotten it to work so far by *explicitly* including readline-rb.. I guess my global require isn't working..

```
gem 'rb-readline', '~> 0.4.2'
```

Comment: Have you looked in Terminal->Preferences->Settings->Keyboard?  Or, Terminal->Preferences->Settings->Advanced->character encoding?

Comment: Terminal is ok. Its Rails Console that is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless another answer comes by, I'll write this for now.

I just wrote into my app itself Readline access with a gem :

```
gem 'rb-readline', '~> 0.4.2'
```

The reason I specifically chose 0.4.2 is because there is an existing bug with later versions as of August 14th 2013.

Somehow when I upgraded OS, the call to my Brew install of Readline was no longer relevant. Not sure why. I imagine there's a way to align the paths again so that it could potentially work globally throughout all my apps, but I only have one internationally sensitive one for now.